# Facebook Login Popup

Tags: facebook, window.open

I'd like to know what code is used in facebook login popup when a user is not signed and click on the like button.

Something like this?

```
<a href="javascript:void( window.open('http://www.example.com/','blank',
'scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=700,height=500'))">Test Popup</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

They use the XFBML implementations of Social Plugins.

First, you have to add an XML namespace attribute to the root  element of your page. Without this declaration, XFBML tags will not render in Internet Explore.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

and put like button code inside your page

```
<fb:like send="true" width="width_value" show_faces="true" />
```

see also : [Like button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Comment: Maybe I don't explain good. I know how add like button to my website, I am interested only on code facebook use to display the login popup window.